# DSL. Is it possible to add commands to context menu item dynamically?

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, dsl

I have DSL Diagram builted in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.
And I want to duplicate TFS functionality like in standard UML Diagrams in Visual Studio ( In my case Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate ). And I have one issue - Types of work items are different in different TFS projects types, which means that I need to add commands in run time. And I don't know how to add some commands to Context Menu dynamically. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
How to: Dynamically Add Menu Items
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb166492.aspx